# Efficient double integration in C with GSL

Tags: c, memory

Consider the double integral

```
I = int int [(a^k)*b] da db
```

where we want to integrate for `a` between `[0,1]` and `b` between `[0,1]` and `k` is some constant. I am using the GSL numerical integration library but have a memory allocation issue.

My code is as follows

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>

double innerIntegrand(double a, void *params) {
    double *cast_params = (double *) params;
    double b = params[0];
    double k = params[1];

    return pow(a,k)*b;
}
```

I can then evaluate the inner integral for a given `b` (to get an outer integrand) as follows

```
double outerIntegrand(double b, void *params) {
    // params = {holder for double b, k}
    double *cast_params = (double *) params;
    cast_params[0] = b;

    // Allocate integration workspace
    gsl_integration_workspace *giw = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(100);

    // Create GSL function
    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &innerIntegrand;
    F.params = params;

    // Initialise values to put the result in
    double result;
    double abserror;

    // Perform integration
    gsl_integration_qag(&F, 0, 1, 0.001, 0.001, 100, 1, giw, &result, &abserror);

    // Free the integration workspace
    gsl_integration_workspace_free(giw);

    // Return result
    return result
}
```

Note however I have to allocate and free the integration workspace within the function. This means it is done many times when evaluating the final integration function

```
double Integral(double k) {
    // Create params
    double *params = malloc(2*sizeof(double));
    params[1] = k;

    // Allocate integration workspace
    gsl_integration_workspace *giw = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(100);

    // Create GSL function
    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &outerIntegrand;
    F.params = params;

    // Initialise values to put the result in
    double result;
    double abserror;

    // Perform integration
    gsl_integration_qag(&F, 0, 1, 0.001, 0.001, 100, 1, giw, &result, &abserror);

    // Free the integration workspace
    gsl_integration_workspace_free(giw);


    // Free memory
    free(params);

    // Return result
    return result
}
```

Ideally what I want is two global `gsl_integration_workspace` variables, one for the integral in `outerIntegrand` and another for the integral in `Integral`. However when I try to declare them as global values I receive a `initializer element is not constant` error.

Can anyone see a way to do this double integral without the repeated memory allocation and freeing? I was thinking we could also pass the workspace in through the `params` argument although it then starts to get quite messy.

Comment: All of your allocations appear to be constant size. Why not just declare an array instead of `malloc()` or `new`-ing? Or, less optimally, allocate in the caller and just pass them into the callee. Allocations  are *very* expensive operations and should not be performed in a tight loop unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, although I don't know any other way to declare the `gsl_integration_workspace` object without the allocation function. Is there a simple way to instead do this instead with an array?

Comment: You said memory allocation issue. Could you give more details regarding that ? Is it that a space of 100 (`size_t`) elements is not enough?

Also, as per this https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/QAG-adaptive-integration.html , you can use the same workspace multiple times.

Comment: The issue is that I am allocating and freeing the workspace multiple times. As the link mentions, one workspace can be used multiple times but I can't work out how to pass that workspace to every inner integration (obviously the outer integration will need a different workspace).

Comment: How about declaring these variables as global with the type `void*`, and then type-casting them explicitly within your functions?

I wonder if this would work?

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives me a `initializer element is not constant` error.

Comment: Ugh... Still worth a try..

Another question - When you declared them as `void*`, did you initialize it to `NULL` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126247/discussion-between-scorpgoku-and-rwolst).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to build a decently looking program in C++ for double integration based on GSL, avoiding repeated allocations in a clean way. I used this well known function to play:

```
f(x,y)=exp(-x*x-y*y)
```

integrating it over all the plane (the result, `pi`, can easily be obtained by switching to polar coordinates).
It is trivial to modify it and add parameters by lambda capture.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>

// Simple RAII wrapper 
class IntegrationWorkspace {
  gsl_integration_workspace * wsp;

  public:
  IntegrationWorkspace(const size_t n=1000):
    wsp(gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(n)) {}
  ~IntegrationWorkspace() { gsl_integration_workspace_free(wsp); }

  operator gsl_integration_workspace*() { return wsp; }
};

// Build gsl_function from lambda
template <typename F>
class gsl_function_pp: public gsl_function {
  const F func;
  static double invoke(double x, void *params) {
    return static_cast<gsl_function_pp*>(params)->func(x);
  }
  public:
  gsl_function_pp(const F& f) : func(f) {
    function = &gsl_function_pp::invoke; //inherited from gsl_function
    params   = this;                     //inherited from gsl_function
  }
  operator gsl_function*(){return this;}
};

// Helper function for template construction
template <typename F>
gsl_function_pp<F> make_gsl_function(const F& func) {
  return gsl_function_pp<F>(func);
}

int main() {
  double epsabs = 1e-8;
  double epsrel = 1e-8;
  size_t limit = 100;
  double result, abserr, inner_result, inner_abserr;

  IntegrationWorkspace wsp1(limit);
  IntegrationWorkspace wsp2(limit);

  auto outer = make_gsl_function( [&](double x) {
    auto inner = make_gsl_function( [&](double y) {return exp(-x*x-y*y);} );
    gsl_integration_qagi(inner, epsabs, epsrel, limit, wsp1,
                         &inner_result, &inner_abserr);
    return inner_result;
  } );
  gsl_integration_qagi(outer, epsabs, epsrel, limit, wsp2, &result, &abserr);

  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks weird:

```
double innerIntegrand(double a, void *params) {
    double *cast_params = (double *) params;
    double b = params[0];
    double k = params[1];
```

Is it correct to expect that (void *)param[0] and [1] correctly map to double b and k? How is proper offset to be calculated between void and double types?

Here some hints (do not expect working code below). 
You may try something like:

```
double b = (double )*param;
double k = (double )*(param + sizeof(double));
```

But probably it would be better and safer to declare:

```
 double Integral(double k) {
     struct p {
         double b;
         double k;
     } params;
     params.k = k;
 ...
    gsl_function F;
   F.function = &outerIntegrand;
   F.params = &params;  

...
double outerIntegrand(double b, void *params) {
   (struct p)params->b = b;

double innerIntegrand(double a, void *params) {
    double b = (struct p)params->b;
    double k = (struct p)params->k;
```

You may want to typdef the "struct p".

Comment: *Is it correct to expect that (void *)param[0] and [1] correctly map to double b and k?* It's a common strategy: `void* param` is used to pass a bunch of stuff into the integrand. It's up to the function to know what it is. In fact, the function should be declared with a pointer to a structure that carries named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need a structure that represents the various parameters needed during integration, as well as the integrator state during integration.

```
enum { MAX_INTEGRALS = 2 };
struct IntegratorState {
    // integration parameters
    size_t wsLimit;
    double limits[MAX_INTEGRALS][2];
    gsl_function func[MAX_INTEGRALS];
    int maxLevel;
    // integration state
    int level;
    gsl_integration_workspace* workspace[MAX_INTEGRALS];
    double x[MAX_INTEGRALS];
    // whatever the innermost integrand needs
    double k;
};

double innerIntegrand(double a, struct IntegratorState* s)
{
    return pow(a, s->k) * s->x[1];
}
```

Now, the `outerIntegrands` do all the integration, calling themselves recursively:

```
double outerIntegrands(double x, struct IntegratorState* s)
{
    const int lvl = s->level++;
    s->x[level] = x;
    double result, abserror;
    gsl_integration_qag(
        &s->func[level], s->limits[level][0], s->limits[level][1],
        0.001, 0.001, s->wsLimit, 1,
        s->workspace[level], &result, &abserror);
    s->level--;
    return result;
}
```

Using the above is rather simple:

```
double integral(double k)
{
    struct IntegratorState s = { 0 };
    s.k = k;
    initIntegratorState(&s, 2);
    setIntegrationLimits(&s, 2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    double result = outerIntegrands(NAN, &s);
    assert(s.level == 0);
    finalizeIntegratorState(&s);
    return result;
}
```

We of also need the utility functions that initialize and tear down the integrator state:

```
void initIntegratorState(struct IntegratorState* s, int maxLevel)
{
    assert(maxLevel <= MAX_INTEGRALS);
    s->level = 0;
    s->maxLevel = maxLevel;
    s->wsLimit = 100;
    for (int level = 0; level < MAX_INTEGRALS; level++) {
        s->workspace[level] = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(s->wsLimit);
        s->func[level] = (gsl_function){ outerIntegrands, s };
    }
    s->func[maxLevel-1] = (gsl_function){ innerIntegrand, s };
}

void setIntegrationLimits(struct IntegratorState* s, int maxLevel, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, maxLevel);
    for (int level = 0; level < maxLevel; level++) {
        s->limits[level][0] = va_arg(args, double);
        s->limits[level][1] = va_arg(args, double);
    }
    va_end(args);
}

void finalizeIntegratorState(struct IntegratorState* s)
{
    for (int level = 0; level < MAX_INTEGRALS; level++) {
        gsl_integration_workspace_free(s->workspace[level]);
        s->workspace[level] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the following:

1. Multiple `IntegratorState`s can coexist. The don't interfere with one another.
2. The `IntegratorState` should be created and initialized before first use. The integrals can be obtained repeatedly using the same state, with either same or different integration limits.
3. The `setIntegrationLimits` function sets the integration limits used in subsequent integrations. It needs to be called to establish the initial limits, and then only if integration over different limits is needed.
4. To keep the integrator performing reasonably well, all memory is preallocated in advance. Integration itself doesn't allocate any memory - only uses what's already there.